# calculate a value basis some conditions and assign it to a new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I am calculating a value of net balance from a condition and I want to store it in a new variable altogether. The new variable should store this calculated value as integer or a float and not as an array

I have tried the following code:

```
  #variable = something if condition else something_else
  mar_final_bal = x_start_bal+df2['credit_line']+df2['Net_Balance'] if 
  df2['month' == 'March-2016']
  apr_final_bal = mar_final_bal+df2['credit_line']+df2['Net_Balance'] if 
  df2['month' == 'Apr-2016']
```

mar_final_bal and apr_final_bal  are my two variables that I want to create using the conditions on the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is evident that you are new to using Pandas. The syntax looks more pseudo-like than pandas code. IIUC, this is what you meant:

```py
mar_final_bal = x_start_bal+df2.loc[df2['month'] == 'March-2016', 'credit_line'].sum() + df2.loc[df2['month'] == 'March-2016', 'Net_Balance'].sum()
apr_final_bal = mar_final_bal+df2.loc[df2['month'] == 'Apr-2016', 'credit_line'].sum() + df2.loc[df2['month'] == 'Apr-2016', 'Net_Balance'].sum()
```

Comment: That solved my issue. I would like to ask one more thing, I would be having 12 such variables month over month and then I want to assign these variables into a new column using the current month column. For example :   df2['month_new']= np.where(df2['month']=='mar_2019',mar_final_bal,0 ) ,will this work? and then I have to assign all such 12 months at once using the newly created variables into one single column

Comment: You probably should have mentioned earlier what you are trying to do in the first place. That won't be an efficient way of doing such things. I suggest asking a new question but with clear definition of your end goal and what the data contains like the first 10 lines of data

Comment: My bad. I will take care of it going forward